# Add common layout in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

This is not an MVC project.

I already created the layout for the site.
I want to add this layout for every page I create. How to add layout for every page?
I tried with the link below but it doesn't work.

```
<%@ Register src="Layout.aspx" tagname="Layout" tagprefix="abc" Inherits="Layout" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

An ASPX is not intended to be "included as a layout".

I think you are looking for something named "MasterPage" : see this for example : http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/aspnet_masterpages.asp , or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fft2ye18%28v=vs.140%29.aspx and all relative pages.

And if you wish to develop some common component for your pages, look for usercontrols (ASCX).

Comment: Thanks you,
Is there any way to stop crashing CSS file in Layout and other pages CSS file??